# Replicate Hawk Authentication in Power Automate?

Tags: authentication, power-automate, power-platform

I hope someone can assist with this - I'm bringing a number of basic API calls into our Power Automate environment to ease the flow of data, and the latest platform I've started working with uses Hawk Authentication - something Microsoft doesn't support.

The protocol appears to be in "maintenance mode" so I don't think Microsoft will be taking it up anytime soon. The platform confirms to me that moving away from Hawk is not on their roadmap.

I'll confess to not knowing much about anything beyond Basic and Oauth authentication methods, so this one has me stumped. I see I need to generate a HMAC value in conjunction with my credentials, and I'm wondering if there's anyway I can recreate this?

I've checked over the [documentation and code](https://github.com/mozilla/hawk/blob/main/API.md) to try to figure out what I might need.

I've got my app ID and Key, the algorithm is sha256.

I *think* I can [create a HMAC](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-createhmac-method/) using Binary functions within Power Automate?

I've got the following to generate a timestamp:

```
div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')),10000000)
```

I'm slightly confused on the Nonce - all the documentation seems to suggest that the Nonce values are 6 digit alphanumeric - something generated by [random.org](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=6&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=plain&rnd=new) could work?

I don't know if I've got the beginnings of a recipe to make this work or not. I'd appreciate some pointers/guidance/suggested next steps!

Comment: This sounds like an interesting one.  I reckon we could get it working with the `C# Script Execute` operation in the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.  It will allow you to complete the task of generating the mac given you can write the necessary code which overcomes short comings in PowerAutomate standard.

Comment: Get ChatGPT to give you some pretty basic boiler plate code that could be used in that operation, it would just need to be tested.  Also, the **nonce** (number used once) needs to be a unique value each time you make a call.  It helps prevent replay attacks by ensuring that each request is unique, even if the same credentials are used multiple times.